# Was Craster conceived or born around the time Bloodraven was at the wall?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I don't think we know *exactly* how old Craster is, just that he's an old man well past his prime, so this might need some estimating based on how many generations of "wives" he has or what Mormont said about how long they've had this arrangement, etc.

I was reading [How did the arrangement between the White Walkers and Craster begin?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/156172/how-did-the-arrangement-between-the-white-walkers-and-craster-begin) and it occurred to me that he's probably about the right age that his conception (by a rogue Night's Watchman with a Wildling north of the wall) might have co-incided with (or, been a direct or indirect consequence of...?) Brandon Rivers AKA Bloodraven's stint as a Night's Watchman, before whatever happened happened that left him stuck under a tree.

Not necessarily saying Bloodraven is the father: there are plenty of other possible links between Bloodraven going on the mission that ends with him stuck in a tree, the others / white walkers coming back, and a man being born who would then somehow end up with this relationship with them. That's beyond the scope here though.

Do these dates match up? Craster's description makes him sound to me maybe 20-30 years younger than Maester Aemon, which seems about right?

Also relevant: are there any other clues about who Craster's father might have been?

Comment: Just my two cents, Bloodraven doesn't strike me as the kinda guy who would have a one night stand with a wildling woman. Only woman he ever loved that we know of is his sister Shiera Seastar (Heh, ASOIAF character redemption). He remained true to his duty and vows to Daeron II even though he loved Daemon Blackfyre (Most likely), so why should he break his vows for a one night stand when he killed his beloved brother and nephews for vows?

Comment: Also Craster can't be that old. Barristan Selmy is pretty old and he is from the reign of King Jaehaerys II. Jaehaerys II was son of Aegon V and Aegon V was son of Maekar I and Maekar I was son of Daeron II. As Bloodraven is brother of Daeron II, the chronology doesn't seem right either

Comment: Interesting idea - I think Brynden Rivers went to the Wall in 233 AC, and Craster is described as "He looked to be a powerful man, though well into the winter of his days now, his mane of hair grey going to white." That's not a huge amount to go on, but it could certainly describe a man in his 60's.

Comment: Not to mention I recall the old man held up in the pen with Arya who said "The Old King wouldn't stand for it", Arya asked if he was talking about Robert. He said no I am talking about Aerys II. So from that we can assume, generally old people are from Aerys II's reign or his father's reign

Comment: Yeah I don't like the idea of Bloodraven being the father (seems contrived as well as out of character), my thinking was more that maybe he went North ranging *in pursuit of* the rogue Night's Watchman who fathered Craster (who maybe did Bad Things that set everything else in motion?).

Comment: Good question, however, unfortunately, I think you've stumbled across one of those times where we probably can't find any more information than yourself :)

Comment: @Aegon "Also Craster can't be that old." Would your further justification not be a claim for Bloodraven being older than a normal human would have been, rather than Craster being relatively young?

Answer (score 4):

According to wiki, [Brynden Rivers](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Brynden_Rivers#Night.27s_Watch) was on the wall between 233AC and 252AC, and [Craster](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Craster) died in 299AC, so between 47 and 66 years old, wich can fit the Craster's description. 
I would say yes, even if we don't know if there is a link between Bloodraven and Craster.

Comment: The wiki surely had a reference to books that stated those dates? At the very least, link to the wiki pages. (IE [text you want to display](link you want the text to link to) )